# What is meaning/significance of +1 in requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1) of Salesforce REST APEX Code

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

What is meaning/significance  of +1 in below Salesforce REST APEX Code

```
            @HttpPatch
                global static ID updateCaseFields() {
                    RestRequest request = RestContext.request;
                    String caseId = request.requestURI.substring(
                        request.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
                    Case thisCase = [SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE Id = :caseId];
                    // Deserialize the JSON string into name-value pairs
                    Map<String, Object> params = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(request.requestbody.tostring());
                    // Iterate through each parameter field and value
                    for(String fieldName : params.keySet()) {
                        // Set the field and value on the Case sObject
                        thisCase.put(fieldName, params.get(fieldName));
                    }
                    update thisCase;
                    return thisCase.Id;
                }    
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That +1 is within the `substring()` function, so it is adding one to the last index of "/" in the request uri in order to grab the case ID.

ex) The URI typically looks something like this:

```
https://<instance>.salesforce.com/Case/<some_case_id>
```

The + 1 allows the substring function to look at one place past the last forward slash "/" to grab the case id at the end of the uri.